# Loop Taking Too Long to Finish in R

Tags: r, loops, vectorization

I have some code which includes a for loop, and nested if statements. The issue is that it is taking too long to run and I want to make it much faster.

I have data on cohorts in a data frame called f2_cebu_davao. There is also a column in this data frame called person_id. There are 3 categories of the cohorts: 'Baseline', 'Other Effects', 'Campaign'.

I want to loop through each person_id in the f2_cebu_davao data frame, and check to see which cohort it is in. If it is in the cohort 'Baseline' or 'Other Effects', then I will check the before_baseline_othereffects table to see if the ID can be found in that table. If it can, I make a new column in the f2_cebu_davao table and the value will be 'returning'. Otherwise, 'new'.

If the cohort name is 'campaign', I will check the before_campaign table and do the same procedure as above.

My data is quite big (all my objects are big) so this is taking a really long time to run (it's been running for more than 30 minutes and still not finished!).

How can I speed this up (possibly by using vectorization, or just by modifying the code a little)?

I tried do loop through but it's taking too long.

```
before_baseline_othereffects <- subset(loans_final_full, submitted_at_date < '2018-05-21')
before_campaign <- subset(loans_final_full, submitted_at_date < '2019-01-21')

for(i in 1:nrow(f2_cebu_davao)){

  if(as.vector(f2_cebu_davao[, 'cohort'][i]) == 'Baseline') {

    if(as.vector(f2_cebu_davao[,'person_id'][i]) %in% as.vector(unique(before_baseline_othereffects$person_id)) == TRUE) {

      f2_cebu_davao$new_or_returning[i] <- 'Returning'

    } else {

      f2_cebu_davao$new_or_returning[i] <- 'New'

    }

  } else if (as.vector(f2_cebu_davao[, 'cohort'][i]) == 'Other Effects'){

     if(as.vector(f2_cebu_davao[,'person_id'][i]) %in% as.vector(unique(before_baseline_othereffects$person_id)) == TRUE) {

      f2_cebu_davao$new_or_returning[i] <- 'Returning'

    } else {

      f2_cebu_davao$new_or_returning[i] <- 'New'

    }



  } else {

    if(as.vector(f2_cebu_davao[,'person_id'][i]) %in% as.vector(unique(before_campaign$person_id)) == TRUE) {

      f2_cebu_davao$new_or_returning[i] <- 'Returning'

    } else {

      f2_cebu_davao$new_or_returning[i] <- 'New'

    }


  }

}
```

Comment: Could you provide some data and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Happy to update and test this if you can provide some example data and desired output. I expect something like this should work.

Here I make up some fake data:

```
f2_cebu_davao <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F,
  cohort = rep(c("Baseline", "Other Effects", "Something else", 
                 "Another Something"), by = 3),
  person_id = 1:12
)
before_baseline_othereffects <- c(1:4)
before_campaign <- c(5:8)
```

Here I apply it using dplyr's `case_when`, spelling out four cases. This code will be vectorized and I expect would run much faster than the current loop code.

1. The cohort is either "Baseline" or "Other Effects, and the person_id appears in `before_baseline_othereffects`. This creates "Returning" in rows 1 & 2.
2. Given the first condition wasn't met, but the cohort is still in either "Baseline" or "Other Effects," return "New," as is done in rows 5 & 6.
3. Given the first two conditions weren't met, but the person was in `before_campaign`, mark Returning, as in rows 7 & 8.
4. Otherwise, mark New, as in rows 3&4 and  9-12.

---

```
library(dplyr)
output <- f2_cebu_davao %>%
  mutate(new_or_returning = case_when(
    cohort %in% c("Baseline", "Other Effects") & 
      person_id %in% before_baseline_othereffects ~ "Returning",
    cohort %in% c("Baseline", "Other Effects")    ~ "New",
    person_id %in% before_campaign                ~ "Returning",
    TRUE                                          ~ "New"
  ))
```

Here's the output:

```
> output
              cohort person_id new_or_returning
1           Baseline         1        Returning
2      Other Effects         2        Returning
3     Something else         3              New
4  Another Something         4              New
5           Baseline         5              New
6      Other Effects         6              New
7     Something else         7        Returning
8  Another Something         8        Returning
9           Baseline         9              New
10     Other Effects        10              New
11    Something else        11              New
12 Another Something        12              New
```